# Why does TTL sometimes re-increment between DNS queries?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, cache, dig, ttl

I `dig xkcd.com`, and I get something like this back:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.1-Ubuntu <<>> xkcd.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 52538
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 5

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;xkcd.com.          IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
xkcd.com.       769 IN  A   107.6.106.82

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
xkcd.com.       87784   IN  NS  dns3.p03.nsone.net.
xkcd.com.       87784   IN  NS  dns1.p03.nsone.net.
xkcd.com.       87784   IN  NS  dns2.p03.nsone.net.
xkcd.com.       87784   IN  NS  dns4.p03.nsone.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
dns1.p03.nsone.net. 70809   IN  A   198.51.44.3
dns2.p03.nsone.net. 70809   IN  A   198.51.45.3
dns3.p03.nsone.net. 71406   IN  A   198.51.44.67
dns4.p03.nsone.net. 70809   IN  A   198.51.45.67

;; Query time: 222 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Jan 21 22:16:42 HKT 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 206
```

The `769` is the cached `TTL` value for `xkcd.com`. However, when I do repeat `dig xkcd.com` several times (within a few seconds of each other), I get a seemingly random `TTL` value everytime. Here's the sequence:

```
TRY | ANSWER | AUTHORITY | ADDITIONAL | WHEN
====================================================================
1   | 586    | 59577     | 44474      | Wed Jan 21 22:18:31 HKT 2015
2   | 587    | 14242     | 56745      | Wed Jan 21 22:18:32 HKT 2015
3   | 658    | 87673     | 70698      | Wed Jan 21 22:18:34 HKT 2015
4   | 1022   | 76200     | 51189      | Wed Jan 21 22:18:40 HKT 2015
5   | 1200   | 160954    | 44662      | Wed Jan 21 22:18:41 HKT 2015
6   | 574    | 59565     | 44462      | Wed Jan 21 22:18:43 HKT 2015
7   | 646    | 87661     | 70686      | Wed Jan 21 22:18:46 HKT 2015
8   | 1200   | 121364    | 55967      | Wed Jan 21 22:18:47 HKT 2015
9   | 1200   | 83292     | 54698      | Wed Jan 21 22:18:48 HKT 2015
10  | 1024   | 40540     | 43816      | Wed Jan 21 22:18:49 HKT 2015
```

**Why do I get this seemingly random (within a range) values for `TTL`? I expect it to decrease gradually, since it is cached.**

Comment: I'd guess you're hitting a load-balanced DNS that corresponds to more than one backend server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dig reports the **time left until the TTL expires** rather than the actual TTL value. If the number varies, it is most likely that you're querying different DNS servers (for example, round robin) which have the record cached for different amounts of time, and therefore have different expiry times.

If you run the same query against the same DNS server, you will see the TTL decrease by (roughly) the same number of seconds you waited between queries. See below:

```
ragnarok:~ cwatson$ dig a cwatson.org @192.168.50.11; sleep 2s; dig a cwatson.org @192.168.50.11

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> a cwatson.org @192.168.50.11
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 39178
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;cwatson.org.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
cwatson.org.        5847    IN  A   46.249.223.150

;; Query time: 43 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.50.11#53(192.168.50.11)
;; WHEN: Wed Jan 21 14:51:08 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 45


; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> a cwatson.org @192.168.50.11
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 24943
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;cwatson.org.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
cwatson.org.        5845    IN  A   46.249.223.150

;; Query time: 45 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.50.11#53(192.168.50.11)
;; WHEN: Wed Jan 21 14:51:10 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 45
```

So, for your full example, you have 769 seconds until the A record expires, which will force a re-lookup from your upstream DNS server.

See the answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/179630/how-can-i-see-time-to-live-ttl-for-a-dns-record) for more detail.

Comment: If so, the `TTL` value should decrease gradually, but it does not. (I appreciate your time in answering me and I didn't downvote you)

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but doesn't Time To Live mean Time until expiration?

Comment: @NickW it does, but there's some ambiguity between "the time until the record expires" and "the TTL of the record". The former is what dig reports.

Comment: @dayuloli - I've just edited my answer with clarification.

Comment: @CraigWatson Thank you for your time. I'll look more into 'round robin' and this 'load balancing' thingymajiggy